# Does a summoned monster's corpse vanish when the spell duration would expire?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, summoning, duration

If I summon an Eagle with [Summon Monster 1](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster) with a duration of 4 turns, but the Eagle dies after only 2 turns, does the corpse vanish after 2 more turns or does it stay on the ground indefinitely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The summoned creature would vanish when it reaches 0 hit points, even if that occurs before the spell duration ends.

For summoned creatures, see the rules for the Summoning sub-school of [conjuration magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Conjuration):

> **Summoning:** a summoning spell instantly brings a creature or object to a place you designate. When the spell ends or is dispelled, a summoned creature is instantly sent back to where it came from, but a summoned object is not sent back unless the spell description specifically indicates this. A summoned creature also goes away if it is killed or if its hit points drop to 0 or lower, but it is not really dead. It takes 24 hours for the creature to reform, during which time it can’t be summoned again.

After being killed (or dropping to 0 hit points or below), the summoned eagle would not leave behind a corpse. Instead it would immediately return to its home plane.